# Isotope vanilla - with custom selectors and data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I am trying to build an isotope demo - with vanilla js features - I want to create custom selectors.

https://jsfiddle.net/s1eympb0/12/

[image]

would sort be the arrangement of elements in the sort I want? In terms of the filtering - this would require a custom selector

```
// bind filter button click
$('.filters-button-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');

  iso.arrange({
   // item element provided as argument
   filter: function( itemElem ) {
     var number = itemElem.querySelector('.number').innerText;
     return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
   }
  });
});


// bind sort button click
$('.sort-by-button-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');

  iso.shuffle();

  //elements - new sorted list?
  //iso.updateSortData( elements ) 
});
```

so have a jquery custom selector used for the filters?

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
  inview: function(el) {
    var $e = $(el),
      $w = $(window),
      top = $e.offset().top,
      height = $e.outerHeight(true),
      windowTop = $w.scrollTop(),
      windowScroll = windowTop - height,
      windowHeight = windowTop + height + $w.height();
    return (top > windowScroll && top < windowHeight);
  }
});
```

and so

```
var newElements = $(".grid-items").is(":inview")
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z1sy2hwq/  - I am trying to get this version working - but something is wrong with the lib

Comment: this is the current version I have - https://jsfiddle.net/s1eympb0/7/

Comment: I've got this version working - but need to turn it into a vanilla version -- https://jsfiddle.net/s1eympb0/9/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s1eympb0/12/  -- this is using a vanilla base now